# How to get all the tr and td from a table in between given two classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

My `table` is of this format:

```
<table id="permissions" class="sticky-enabled tableheader-processed sticky-table permissions-processed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Permission</th>
            <th class="checkbox">Staff</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="module" id="module-heartbeat_ui" colspan="2">Heartbeat UI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-admin-heartbeat-configure" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    Configure heartbeat
                    <div class="description">Manage the heartbeat streams and configuration settings.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-admin-heartbeat-configure">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-configure">Staff: Configure heartbeat </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-configure" name="4[admin heartbeat configure]" value="admin heartbeat configure"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="module" id="module-heartbeat" colspan="2">Heartbeat activity</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-admin-heartbeat-templates" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    Administer heartbeat templates
                    <div class="description">Manage the heartbeat templates.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-admin-heartbeat-templates">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-templates">Staff: Administer heartbeat templates </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-templates" name="4[admin heartbeat templates]" value="admin heartbeat templates"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-admin-heartbeat-delete-all" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    Delete all activity
                    <div class="description">Master permission to delete all activity.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-admin-heartbeat-delete-all">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-delete-all">Staff: Delete all activity </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-delete-all" name="4[admin heartbeat delete all]" value="admin heartbeat delete all"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-admin-heartbeat-delete-own" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    Delete own activity
                    <div class="description">Permission for the actor to delete own activity.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-admin-heartbeat-delete-own">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-delete-own">Staff: Delete own activity </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-delete-own" name="4[admin heartbeat delete own]" value="admin heartbeat delete own"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-view-heartbeat-messages" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    View activity
                    <div class="description">Global permission to view heartbeat activity.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-view-heartbeat-messages">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-view-heartbeat-messages">Staff: View activity </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-view-heartbeat-messages" name="4[view heartbeat messages]" value="view heartbeat messages"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-access-heartbeat-activity-profiles" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    Access heartbeat activity profiles
                    <div class="description">Permission to see user profiles or links to the user profile.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-access-heartbeat-activity-profiles">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-access-heartbeat-activity-profiles">Staff: Access heartbeat activity profiles </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-access-heartbeat-activity-profiles" name="4[access heartbeat activity profiles]" value="access heartbeat activity profiles"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox"
                        disabled="disabled" checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-view-single-activity-stream" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    View activity in Single activity
                    <div class="description">Stream access: Single activity.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-view-Single-activity-stream">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-view-single-activity-stream">Staff: View activity in Single activity </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-view-single-activity-stream" name="4[view Single activity stream]" value="view Single activity stream"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-view-views-activity-stream" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    View activity in Views activity
                    <div class="description">Stream access: Views activity.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-view-Views-activity-stream">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-view-views-activity-stream">Staff: View activity in Views activity </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-view-views-activity-stream" name="4[view Views activity stream]" value="view Views activity stream"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="module" id="module-hide_modules" colspan="2">Hide Modules</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-edit-webform-components" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    Content authors: access and edit webform components and settings
                    <div class="description">Grants additional access to the webform components and settings to users who can edit the content. Generally an authenticated user permission.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-edit-webform-components">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-edit-webform-components">Staff: Content authors: access and edit webform components and settings </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-edit-webform-components" name="4[edit webform components]" value="edit webform components" checked="checked"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox"
                        disabled="disabled" checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to find all the `tr` of the table in between `td`'s `class="module" id="module-heartbeat_ui"` and `class="module" id="module-heartbeat"` using jQuery. Is there any shorthand jQuery code to grab those occrances of `tr` and `td`'s in between.

Comment: So, you want to use leaves of a tree to determine a range for parents?

Comment: it seems more so like you are just trying to get the value of the UI, located in the TR:odd

Comment: Are you looking for code to work for this one instance or will it apply to different tables? If you only need for this table then you might as well simply get the first instance of `<tr class="odd">`

Comment: I dont think you can find a 'clean' selector for this, you will have to iterate.

Comment: @Fallenreaper : Trying to get all elements in between given two classes of td

Comment: @Milson in your test case, they aren't siblings, therefore there is not concept of "in between".   They are in different trees no?

Comment: @Fallenreaper : consider from tbody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use nextUtil

```js
$('tr:has("td#module-heartbeat_ui")').nextUntil('tr:has("td#module-heartbeat")').addBack().find("td").css("background-color","yellow")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="permissions" class="sticky-enabled tableheader-processed sticky-table permissions-processed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Permission</th>
            <th class="checkbox">Staff</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="module" id="module-heartbeat_ui" colspan="2">Heartbeat UI</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-admin-heartbeat-configure" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    Configure heartbeat
                    <div class="description">Manage the heartbeat streams and configuration settings.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-admin-heartbeat-configure">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-configure">Staff: Configure heartbeat </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-configure" name="4[admin heartbeat configure]" value="admin heartbeat configure"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="module" id="module-heartbeat" colspan="2">Heartbeat activity</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-admin-heartbeat-templates" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    Administer heartbeat templates
                    <div class="description">Manage the heartbeat templates.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-admin-heartbeat-templates">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-templates">Staff: Administer heartbeat templates </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-templates" name="4[admin heartbeat templates]" value="admin heartbeat templates"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-admin-heartbeat-delete-all" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    Delete all activity
                    <div class="description">Master permission to delete all activity.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-admin-heartbeat-delete-all">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-delete-all">Staff: Delete all activity </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-delete-all" name="4[admin heartbeat delete all]" value="admin heartbeat delete all"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-admin-heartbeat-delete-own" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    Delete own activity
                    <div class="description">Permission for the actor to delete own activity.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-admin-heartbeat-delete-own">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-delete-own">Staff: Delete own activity </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-admin-heartbeat-delete-own" name="4[admin heartbeat delete own]" value="admin heartbeat delete own"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-view-heartbeat-messages" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    View activity
                    <div class="description">Global permission to view heartbeat activity.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-view-heartbeat-messages">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-view-heartbeat-messages">Staff: View activity </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-view-heartbeat-messages" name="4[view heartbeat messages]" value="view heartbeat messages"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-access-heartbeat-activity-profiles" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    Access heartbeat activity profiles
                    <div class="description">Permission to see user profiles or links to the user profile.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-access-heartbeat-activity-profiles">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-access-heartbeat-activity-profiles">Staff: Access heartbeat activity profiles </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-access-heartbeat-activity-profiles" name="4[access heartbeat activity profiles]" value="access heartbeat activity profiles"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox"
                        disabled="disabled" checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-view-single-activity-stream" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    View activity in Single activity
                    <div class="description">Stream access: Single activity.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-view-Single-activity-stream">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-view-single-activity-stream">Staff: View activity in Single activity </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-view-single-activity-stream" name="4[view Single activity stream]" value="view Single activity stream"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-view-views-activity-stream" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    View activity in Views activity
                    <div class="description">Stream access: Views activity.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-view-Views-activity-stream">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-view-views-activity-stream">Staff: View activity in Views activity </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-view-views-activity-stream" name="4[view Views activity stream]" value="view Views activity stream"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox" disabled="disabled"
                        checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="module" id="module-hide_modules" colspan="2">Hide Modules</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="permission">
                <div id="edit-edit-webform-components" class="form-item form-type-item">
                    Content authors: access and edit webform components and settings
                    <div class="description">Grants additional access to the webform components and settings to users who can edit the content. Generally an authenticated user permission.</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="checkbox">
                <div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-4-edit-webform-components">
                    <label class="element-invisible" for="edit-4-edit-webform-components">Staff: Content authors: access and edit webform components and settings </label>
                    <input class="rid-4 form-checkbox real-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="edit-4-edit-webform-components" name="4[edit webform components]" value="edit webform components" checked="checked"><input type="checkbox" class="dummy-checkbox"
                        disabled="disabled" checked="checked" title="This permission is inherited from the authenticated user role." style="display: none;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: addBack() is this function available on jQuery old Versions? from which version they roll it out?

Comment: Right in the documentation http://api.jquery.com/addback/ it tells you what version.

Comment: If you are using 1.7 which is like 6 years old, it has andSelf

Answer (score -2):

In JavaScript you can get table element HTML code and split by
`<tr>`
Then loop each tr to get td's

Or using jquery you could to it like this:

```
$('#table_id, .table-class > tbody > tr').each(function(value, index){/*You code here*/});
```